# Get files from a directory and add them to a list that is updating constantly. VB

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have been looking everywhere for something that will constantly check a directory to see if there are any new files and if there is it will add that files name to a list

I have this but it only works when i click on the list

```
   Dim JAR As String = "*.jpg"
    Dim DirInfo As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(dir)
    Dim Files() As FileInfo = DirInfo.GetFiles(JAR, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Dim File As FileInfo
    Const extension As String = ".jpg"
    For Each File In Files
        If (Not list.Items.Contains(File.Name)) Then
            list.Items.Add(File.Name)
            list.Text.Substring(0, ClientList.Text.Length - extension.Length)
            list.Text = list.Items.Count
        End If
    Next (File)
```

Comment: Is this code in listbox click_event ?

Comment: Search for FileSystemWatcher class

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the [FileSystemWatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

> Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.

Answer (score 0):

one simple solution is to check if that file is created today.

```
    Dim files As FileSystemInfo
    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\myDirectory\"

    Dim childinfo As New DirectoryInfo(path)

        For Each files As FileSystemInfo In childinfo.GetFileSystemInfos()

            ' Select only files within the day (format: MM/DD/YY)
            ' It does not include old files being kept in the folder

            If files.CreationTime.Date.Equals(Date.Today) Then
                list.Add(path & files.Name)
            End If

        Next
```

But it will be a good option to see FileSystemWatcher Class.